# roundrectGrob equivalent for geom_rect in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make the graph appending on a background protein backbone (drawing using geom_rect() function). is there any way to create the round-edged rectangle instead of the basic rectangle (specifically for the red rectangle).
Here is the code I have used.

I have tried the roundrectGrob() function from `grid` but getting the error `Error: Don't know how to add roundrectGrob(x = 28, y = -2.3, width = 22, height = 0.45) to a plot`

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot() +
ylim(-4, 4) +
xlim(0, 100)
## First rect
p <- p + geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=10,
xmax=90,
ymin=-2.15,
ymax=-2.00),
colour = "black",
fill = "grey")
## Second rect
p <- p + geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=28,
xmax=50,
ymin=-2.30,
ymax=-1.85),
colour = "black",
fill = "red")
# print
p
dev.off()
```

[image: Protein pfam structure for plot]

Comment: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/statebins/blob/master/R/geom-rrect.r

Comment: Tried it already. But got this error. p + geom_rrect(mapping=aes(xmin=28,
+ xmax=50,
+ ymin=-2.30,
+ ymax=-1.85),
+ colour = "black",
+ fill = "red")
Error in geom_rrect(mapping = aes(xmin = 28, xmax = 50, ymin = -2.3, ymax = -1.85),  : 
  could not find function "geom_rrect" .

Comment: I was (lazily) implying you could copy the source into your session 

Comment: note: you'll need to call `statebins:::geom_rrect()` to use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @hrbrmstr, after installing `statebins` with

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/statebins")
```

try this

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot() + ylim(-4, 4) + xlim(0, 100)
## First rect
p <- p + geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=10,
         xmax=90, ymin=-2.15,  ymax=-2.00),
         colour = "black", fill = "grey")
## Second rect
p <- p + statebins:::geom_rrect(mapping=aes(xmin=28, 
         xmax=50, ymin=-2.30, ymax=-1.85),  
         colour = "black", fill = "red")
# Print
p
```

[image]

Comment: If it would help to properly export this I can make the change and push to CRAN. It just means I have to document the function and I was just too lazy before